# Can I use Delegates to cache Functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, function-pointers

Say I have a Script Accessing a function, multiple times, belonging to another class as follows, (Exaggerated):

```
void Update(){
       for (int i= 0; i< 10; i++){
            object1.object2.object3.Function();
    }
}
```

And I replace it with,

```
delegate void MyDelegate();
MyDelegate myFunction;


    void Start(){
    myFunction =  object1.object2.object3.Function;
    }
    
    void Update(){
    for (int i= 0; i< 10; i++){
                this.myFunction();
        }
    }
```

Does this have any performance Impact(even minimal), as I am thinking about cache hits and misses when de-referencing these Objects or am I completely wrong about in my Understanding of delegates and its usage?

**Edit :**
So, I did a small Benchmark with the above code, and used the Stopwatch Class from Diagnostics to measure the elapsed time. And yeah, there wasn't any glaring differences between these two.

I iterated through a function which calculated the square root of a floating point, 100000 times and measured the elapsed time and it came around 6000ms on both cases.

Comment: Race your horses, let us know

Comment: Technically there is nothing wrong doing like this. But this not catching. Delegate is like a variable which points to a function. You can also pass function as method parameter using delegate.

Comment: Technically there is a measurable performance hit with using delegates as opposed to calling a method directly, but you need to ask how does that compare to the work actually being done in the method.  Virtual methods have a cost too. @Priyank is correct that it is not “caching”

Comment: Just avoid the chain by setting a variable outside the loop. 'var a = object1.object2.object3;'... then 'a.Update();' in the loop.

Comment: there is a very slight positive impact to doing this but I believe it would be bordering on unmeasurable. We have spent more time writing those comments than you app will spend in a hundered years

Comment: @zambari Incorrect. It is a _huge_ impact. A `delegate` call is **40** times slower than an average instance method call. _[Writing Faster Managed Code: Know What Things Cost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx)_

Comment: @MickyD But I just did some benchmarking and I didn't notice such degradation on Performance when using Delegates.

Comment: Good for you.  That’s the best way to learn :)

Comment: @MickyD delegates are slower and function calls can be a drag, but the question was (I beliece) refering to caching object dereferencing, not getting rid of the super-handy delegadte approach altogether